# Why do I get NPE in the following code?

Tags: clojure, lisp, macros

The following code executes as expected but gives a `NullPointerException` at the end. What am I doing wrong here?

```
(ns my-first-macro)

(defmacro exec-all [& commands]
  (map (fn [c] `(println "Code: " '~c "\t=>\tResult: " ~c)) commands))

(exec-all
  (cons 2 [4 5 6])
  ({:k 3 :m 8} :k)
  (conj [4 5 \d] \e \f))

; Output:
; Clojure 1.2.0-master-SNAPSHOT
; Code:  (cons 2 [4 5 6])   =>  Result:  (2 4 5 6)
; Code:  ({:k 3, :m 8} :k)  =>  Result:  3
; Code:  (conj [4 5 d] e f)     =>  Result:  [4 5 d e f]
; java.lang.NullPointerException (MyFirstMacro.clj:0)
; 1:1 user=> #<Namespace my-first-macro>
; 1:2 my-first-macro=>
```

(For properly syntax highlighted code, go [here](http://paste.pocoo.org/show/237463/).)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Take a look at the expansion that is happening:

```
(macroexpand '(exec-all (cons 2 [4 5 6])))
=>
((clojure.core/println "Code: " (quote (cons 2 [4 5 6])) "\t=>\tResult: " (cons 2 [4 5 6])))
```

As you can see, there is an extra pair of parentheses around your expansion, which means that Clojure tries to execute the result of the println function, which is nil.

To fix this I'd suggest modifying the macro to include a "do" at the front, e.g.

```
(defmacro exec-all [& commands]
  (cons 'do (map (fn [c] `(println "Code: " '~c "\t=>\tResult: " ~c)) commands)))
```

Comment: Sure, you could rewrite it to expand to a `doseq` etc. But why? This is a perfectly reasonable solution and the change to your existing code is minimal; I'd say stick with it.

Comment: @Michael: because I believe knowing alternative ways will aid in my Clojure learning.

Comment: Another option I guess would be to change the output of each function to a string rather than a println and concatenate them all together. I think this is the natural "side effect free" way of doing this.

Comment: @Rahuλ G: Fair enough. I'll add another answer with a `doseq`-based version.

Comment: ...obviously after upvoting the best way of fixing the problem displayed in the answer above. :-)

Answer (score 6):

Since the OP asked for other possible ways of writing this macro (see comments on the accepted answer), here goes:

```
(defmacro exec-all [& commands]
  `(doseq [c# ~(vec (map (fn [c]
                           `(fn [] (println "Code: " '~c "=> Result: " ~c)))
                         commands))]
     (c#)))
```

This expands to something like

```
(doseq [c [(fn []
             (println "Code: "      '(conj [2 3 4] 5)
                      "=> Result: " (conj [2 3 4] 5)))
           (fn []
             (println "Code: "      '(+ 1 2)
                      "=> Result: " (+ 1 2)))]]
  (c))
```

Note that the `fn` forms whose values will be bound to `c` are collected in a vector at macro-expansion time.

Needless to say, the original version is simpler, thus I think `(do ...)` is the perfect fix. :-)

Example interaction:

```
user=> (exec-all (conj [2 3 4] 5) (+ 1 2))                                                                                                    
Code:  (conj [2 3 4] 5) => Result:  [2 3 4 5]
Code:  (+ 1 2) => Result:  3
nil
```